# Convert a Unix ImageMagick script to a Windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, imagemagick

I'm trying to convert this code to a batch file. I installed ImageMagick, but I'm really bad in converting to batch code. Can you help me?

```unix
#! /usr/bin/env bash
find -E '/Users/Me/Desktop/ResizeImagesFolder' -type f -iregex '.*\.(JPG|JPEG|PNG|TIF|TIFF)$' |\
  while read FULL_IMAGE_PATH
  do
    convert -density 72 -units PixelsPerInch -resize "1200x1200>" -quality 90 "${FULL_IMAGE_PATH}" "${FULL_IMAGE_PATH}"
    composite -compose atop -geometry +15 -gravity southwest  ./watermark-photos.png "${FULL_IMAGE_PATH}" "${FULL_IMAGE_PATH}"
  done
```

Comment: Try writing the FOR loop using this... http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no method of testing this but I suspect it will be extremely close... and no-one else is offering any help so please try and work with it if there are some minor glitches.

The original bash code is not that good itself, so I have made it into a single command at the same time.

It assumes your watermark is saved in the current directory as `watermark.png`.

**PLEASE TEST ON A SAMPLE COPY OF YOUR IMAGES AFTER MAKING A BACKUP**

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /R E:\ %%G IN (*.PNG *.JPG *.BMP) DO (
   ECHO %%G
   convert -density 72 -units PixelsPerInch "%%G" -resize "1200x1200>" -quality 90 -gravity southwest watermark.png -geometry +15 -compose atop -composite "%%G"
)
```

I have assumed your images are in `E:\` for no particular reason.